# Could Anyone Show List of Button Face Id in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to create costum menu button using VBA in my excel 2010 file using predefined excel button that use face id.  In my case i would like to use "lock" and "refresh" icon, but doesn`t know the face id for that icon.  could anyone show or point me the list of button and face id used in excel 2010?

Comment: I can't confirm the contents of this document as I have office 2007 but Microsoft hosts an "Office Icon Gallery" document http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21103

Comment: Yes, i have try that add-in but it only show the icon, i want to know what the id  of that i con so that i could use in my VBA Script.

Comment: Did you see my comment regarding hovering over the button to display the faceid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following **Sub BarOpen()** works with Excel 2010, most probably also many other versions also, and generates in the Tab "Add-Ins" a custom, temporary toolbar with drop-downs to show the FaceIDs from 1 .. 5020 in groups of 30 items.

```
Option Explicit

Const APP_NAME = "FaceIDs (Browser)"

' The number of icons to be displayed in a set.
Const ICON_SET = 30

Sub BarOpen()
  Dim xBar As CommandBar
  Dim xBarPop As CommandBarPopup
  Dim bCreatedNew As Boolean
  Dim n As Integer, m As Integer
  Dim k As Integer

  On Error Resume Next
  ' Try to get a reference to the 'FaceID Browser' toolbar if it exists and delete it:
  Set xBar = CommandBars(APP_NAME)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not xBar Is Nothing Then
    xBar.Delete
    Set xBar = Nothing
  End If

  Set xBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=APP_NAME, Temporary:=True) ', Position:=msoBarLeft
  With xBar
    .Visible = True
    '.Width = 80
    For k = 0 To 4 ' 5 dropdowns, each for about 1000 FaceIDs
      Set xBarPop = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup) ', Before:=1
      With xBarPop
        .BeginGroup = True
        If k = 0 Then
          .Caption = "Face IDs " & 1 + 1000 * k & " ... "
        Else
          .Caption = 1 + 1000 * k & " ... "
        End If
        n = 1
        Do
          With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup) '34 items * 30 items = 1020 faceIDs
            .Caption = 1000 * k + n & " ... " & 1000 * k + n + ICON_SET - 1
            For m = 0 To ICON_SET - 1
              With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) '
                .Caption = "ID=" & 1000 * k + n + m
                .FaceId = 1000 * k + n + m
              End With
            Next m
          End With
          n = n + ICON_SET
        Loop While n < 1000 ' or 1020, some overlapp
      End With
    Next k
  End With 'xBar
End Sub
```

Comment: Still works in Excel 2016.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look here:

[Face ID's](http://skp.mvps.org/faceid.htm)

Its an addin for MS excel. Works for excel 97 and later.

Comment: i try that add-in but it only show me the button, the face id itself remain unknown.

Comment: hold your mouse over the button the face id will pop up.

Answer (score 2):

I put together my own list of button face ID's. I used Excel VBA code to test all the toolface numbers up to 100,000. There were faces for ID numbers up to almost 34,000. Most of these had duplicates, which make them harder to look through. I compared all the faces to each other using a VBA arraylist, and only kept the first instance of each one. I think this file shows all the toolfaces with their numbers, but it only shows each one once:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q7y7uf3tuy02uu/FaceID%20Excel%202021.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Modified previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36217862) to create numerous toolbars with sets of 10 icons. Can change code (comment/un-comment) number of toolbars (performance may be slow on slower machines)

The last icon number for Office 2013 that I could find was 25424 for OneDrive

```vb
Sub FaceIdsOutput()
' ==================================================
' FaceIdsOutput Macro
' ==================================================
' =========================
Dim sym_bar As CommandBar
Dim cmd_bar As CommandBar
' =========================
Dim i_bar As Integer
Dim n_bar_ammt As Integer
Dim i_bar_start As Integer
Dim i_bar_final As Integer
' =========================
Dim icon_ctrl As CommandBarControl
' =========================
Dim i_icon As Integer
Dim n_icon_step As Integer
Dim i_icon_start As Integer
Dim i_icon_final As Integer
' =========================
n_icon_step = 10
' =========================
i_bar_start = 1
n_bar_ammt =  500
' i_bar_start = 501
' n_bar_ammt =  1000
' i_bar_start = 1001
' n_bar_ammt =  1500
' i_bar_start = 1501
' n_bar_ammt =  2000
' i_bar_start = 2001
' n_bar_ammt =  2543
i_bar_final = i_bar_start + n_bar_ammt - 1
' =========================
' delete toolbars
' =========================
For Each cmd_bar In Application.CommandBars
    If InStr(cmd_bar.Name,"Symbol") <> 0 Then
        cmd_bar.Delete
    End If
Next
' =========================
' create toolbars
' =========================
For i_bar = i_bar_start To i_bar_final
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sym_bar = Application.CommandBars.Add _
        ("Symbol" & i_bar, msoBarFloating, Temporary:=True)
    ' =========================
    ' create buttons
    ' =========================
    i_icon_start = (i_bar-1) * n_icon_step + 1
    i_icon_final = i_icon_start + n_icon_step - 1
    For i_icon = i_icon_start To i_icon_final
        Set icon_ctrl = sym_bar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
        icon_ctrl.FaceId = i_icon
        icon_ctrl.TooltipText = i_icon
        Debug.Print ("Symbol = " & i_icon)
    Next i_icon
    sym_bar.Visible = True
Next i_bar
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub DeleteFaceIdsToolbar()
' ==================================================
' DeleteFaceIdsToolbar Macro
' ==================================================
Dim cmd_bar As CommandBar
For Each cmd_bar In Application.CommandBars
    If InStr(cmd_bar.Name,"Symbol") <> 0 Then
        cmd_bar.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice and handy overview of FaceIds on the 'Add-in' Ribbon bar.

Answer (score 0):

short script writes ten (loop set for 10) FaceID's add. as entry into toolbar Tab "Add-In" and with "Benutzerdefinierte Symbolliste löschen" - you erase this add entry ( mark and right mouse click) - works with excel 2010/2013

```
Sub FaceIdsAusgeben()
Dim symb As CommandBar
Dim Icon As CommandBarControl
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set symb = Application.CommandBars.Add _
("Symbole", msoBarFloating)
For i = 1 To 10
Set Icon = symb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
Icon.FaceId = i
Icon.TooltipText = i
Debug.Print ("Symbole = " & i)
Next i
symb.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

script provides on worksheet name of controls excel 2010/2013

```
Sub IDsErmitteln()
Dim crtl As CommandBarControl
Dim i As Integer
Worksheets.Add
On Error Resume Next
i = 1
For Each crtl In Application.CommandBars(1).Controls(1).Controls
Cells(i, 1).Value = crtl.Caption
Cells(i, 2).Value = crtl.ID
i = i + 1
Next crtl
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I found it in this location what i`m looking at

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;[LN];Q213552

The table contain the Control and id (Face Id) used in excel. So for "Refresh" button the face id is 459, but it only work on the id less than 3 digit.

and this generator(by input start face id and end face id) then click show button faces, you get the list of icon on the range (to download it must login first)

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39992

and this for Ribbon Toolbar

http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm