# Why are the icons different if they have the same FaceID?

Tags: excel, vba

I get the icons for popup menus with two different codes. Why are they different if they have the same FaceID?

Not only the type of icons (one type Excel 2003 and another Excel 365) There are also different icons, as we can be seen in the image.

[image]

What code should I use in my popup menu to get the Excel 365 style?

I create my popup menu with this code and I can't get the Excel 365 icon:

```
With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=gsMENUNOTES, _
  Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .Caption = "New note"
        .OnAction = "NewNote"
        .FaceId = 4385
    End With
End With
```

[image]

This is the code to get the icons (Excel 365 type) on the Ribbon (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364215/11185212)

```
Option Explicit

Const APP_NAME = "FaceIDs (Browser)"

' The number of icons to be displayed in a set.
Const ICON_SET = 30

Sub BarOpen()
  Dim xBar As CommandBar
  Dim xBarPop As CommandBarPopup
  Dim bCreatedNew As Boolean
  Dim n As Integer, m As Integer
  Dim k As Integer

  On Error Resume Next
  ' Try to get a reference to the 'FaceID Browser' toolbar if it exists and delete it:
  Set xBar = CommandBars(APP_NAME)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not xBar Is Nothing Then
    xBar.Delete
    Set xBar = Nothing
  End If

  Set xBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=APP_NAME, Temporary:=True) ', Position:=msoBarLeft
  With xBar
    .Visible = True
    '.Width = 80
    For k = 0 To 4 ' 5 dropdowns, each for about 1000 FaceIDs
      Set xBarPop = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup) ', Before:=1
      With xBarPop
        .BeginGroup = True
        If k = 0 Then
          .Caption = "Face IDs " & 1 + 1000 * k & " ... "
        Else
          .Caption = 1 + 1000 * k & " ... "
        End If
        n = 1
        Do
          With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup) '34 items * 30 items = 1020 faceIDs
            .Caption = 1000 * k + n & " ... " & 1000 * k + n + ICON_SET - 1
            For m = 0 To ICON_SET - 1
              With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) '
                .Caption = "ID=" & 1000 * k + n + m
                .FaceId = 1000 * k + n + m
              End With
            Next m
          End With
          n = n + ICON_SET
        Loop While n < 1000 ' or 1020, some overlapp
      End With
    Next k
  End With 'xBar
End Sub
```

And this is the code to get the icons (Excel 2003 type) on the sheet (https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/face-id-in-column-with-their-names-in-excel-sheet-using-vba.567230/)

```
Option Explicit

Sub exa()
    Dim CB          As CommandBar
    Dim ctl         As CommandBarButton
    Dim strCBName   As String
    Dim wbTemp      As Workbook
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim rngInput    As Range
    Dim i           As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    wbTemp.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FaceID.xlsx"
    Dim NID As Long
    Dim NSheet As Long
    For NSheet = 1 To 5
        '// Add a temp commandbar, make it a popup (which we won't show); add a temp control //
        Set CB = CommandBars.Add(Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    
        Set ctl = CB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
        strCBName = CB.Name
    
        Set wks = wbTemp.Worksheets(NSheet)
        Dim vlFrom As Long
        vlFrom = ((NSheet - 1) * 50 * 20) + 1
        Dim vlTo As Long
        vlTo = NSheet * 50 * 20
        wks.Name = "F.ID " & vlFrom & "-" & vlTo
        Dim Col As Integer
        For Col = 2 To 40 Step 2
            Dim LCol As String
            LCol = Split(wks.Cells(1, Col).Address, "$")(1)
            Set rngInput = wks.Range(LCol & ":" & LCol)
    
            rngInput.Offset(, -1).ColumnWidth = 3
            rngInput.ColumnWidth = 8
            rngInput.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
            On Error Resume Next
            For i = 1 To 50
                NID = NID + 1
                ctl.FaceId = NID
                ctl.CopyFace
                rngInput.Cells(i).PasteSpecial
                rngInput.Cells(i).Value = NID
            Next i
        Next Col
        '// just so the last image pasted doesn't stay selected//
        Application.GoTo wks.Cells(1, 1)
        wbTemp.Sheets.Add After:=wbTemp.Sheets(wbTemp.Sheets.Count)
        'Debug.Print NSheet
        'DoEvents
        '// Kill the temp cbar and ctrl //
        Set CB = CommandBars(strCBName)
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        If Not CB Is Nothing Then
            CB.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "ACK!  I lost a toolbar!", 0, vbNullString
        End If
    Next NSheet
    
    wbTemp.Save
    
End Sub
```